# Userform input field to accept ONLY minutes and seconds

Tags: excel, input, time, vba

I have searched for this code and only found input for hours, minutes and seconds and have tried to adapt the found code to no avail.

I want an entry field in a userform to accept 3 or 4 digits as an input of which the first 1 or 2 will be assigned to the minutes and the last 2 digits assigned to the seconds of a minutes:seconds cell in a spreadsheet?

eg. User inputs 0523 which is transferred to a cell in excel as 5:23
or User inputs 523 which is transferred to a cell in excel as 5:23

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you there.  It will check the values and format the textbox as you type.

```
'Global variable
Dim bBail as boolean

'Textbox change event
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
Dim strText As String
Dim oTime As Date

    'Check if we are seeing a change because we are setting the value
    If bBail = True Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Get the value in the textbox
    strText = Trim(TextBox2.Text)

    'Take out any semicolons we have in the text
    strText = Replace(strText, ":", "")

    'Make sure we have valid hours
    If Len(strText) > 1 Then
        If Val(Left(strText, 2)) > 12 Then
            MsgBox ("Invalid Input")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    'Make sure we have valid minutes
    If Len(strText) > 3 Then
        If Val(Right(strText, 2)) > 59 Then
            MsgBox ("Invalid Input")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    'Format for the textbox
    If Len(strText) > 2 Then
        strText = Left(strText, 2) & ":" & Right(strText, Len(strText) - 2)
    End If

    'Write the time value to the text box.
    bBail = True
    TextBox2.Text = strText
    bBail = False

End Sub
```

Here in the textbox keypress event we will make sure that only numbers can be entered into the textbox.

```
Private Sub TextBox2_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)

    'Limit the length of the text. Can be done in textbox properties as well
    If Len(TextBox2.Text) > 4 Then
        KeyAscii = 0
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If KeyAscii = 8 Then Exit Sub
    If Chr(KeyAscii) < "0" Or Chr(KeyAscii) > "9" Then
        KeyAscii = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just what I needed.
Thank you.

Comment: Thought about it and realized that I needed to make a change.  The `bBail = True` and `bBail = False` need moved down around the `.text =` line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim tbV As String
 Dim sV As String
 Dim mV As String
 Dim Rng As Range

 tbV = Me.TextBox1.Text

 If Len(tbV) > 4 Or Len(tbV) < 2 Or Not IsNumeric(tbV) Then
  MsgBox "wrong"
  Exit Sub
 End If

 Set Rng = Selection ' change this as you need

 sV = Right(tbV, 2)
 mV = Left(tbV, Len(tbV) - 2)
 Rng.NumberFormat = "m:ss"
 Rng.Value = TimeSerial(0, Val(mV), Val(sV))

End Sub
```

test:

input 523 , result 5:23

input 0523 , result 5:23

input 6523 , result 5:23 (but the value is 01:05:23)

input 23 , result 0:23

Comment: Brilliant!
Thank you.